# XSLT/XPATH : filtering of a multi-level XML file based on attributes values

Tags: xslt, xpath

I am new to XSLT and I was not able to find a similar case among the posts.

I have to filter a big XML file where the root DOCUMENT have children as ITEM or FOLDER.
An ITEM contains one or more TOPIC. A FOLDER contains at least one ITEM or one FOLDER.
Each TOPIC owns an ID taken from a common list of IDs.

This XML is filtered upon a sublist from the common ID list according to :
(i) For an ITEM to be kept, it must have at least one TOPIC with an ID among the sublist,
(ii) For a FOLDER to be kept, it must have at least one ITEM satisfying (i).

I did not manage to have those two criteria satisfied with my XSLT.

The consequence is that some empty ITEMs and FOLDERs remain empty whereas they should go.
In the example below, the list of IDs is 31,46,54,72.
The sublist of IDs to be kept is 31 (may be more than one but to simplify I use one)

My input XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DOCUMENT name="myname">
 <FOLDER key="1">
  <FOLDER key="11">
   <FOLDER key="111">
    <FOLDER key="1111">
     <FOLDER key="11111">
      <ITEM key="11111a">
       <TOPIC id="31" key="11111a1">
        <REF link="11111a1"/>
       </TOPIC>
      </ITEM>
     </FOLDER>
     <FOLDER key="11112">
      <ITEM key="11112a">
       <TOPIC id="46" key="11112a1">
        <REF link="11112a1"/>
       </TOPIC>
      </ITEM>
      <ITEM key="11112b">
       <TOPIC id="54" key="11112b1">
        <REF link="11112b1"/>
       </TOPIC>
       <TOPIC id="72" key="11112b2">
        <REF link="11112b2"/>
       </TOPIC>
      </ITEM>
     </FOLDER>
    </FOLDER>
    <FOLDER key="1112">
     <FOLDER key="11121">
      <ITEM key="11121a">
       <TOPIC id="31" key="11121a1">
        <REF link="11121a1"/>
       </TOPIC>
      </ITEM>
     </FOLDER>
     <FOLDER key="11122">
      <ITEM key="11122a">
       <TOPIC id="46" key="11122a1">
        <REF link="11122a1"/>
       </TOPIC>
      </ITEM>
      <ITEM key="11122b">
       <TOPIC id="46" key="11122b1">
        <REF link="11122b1"/>
       </TOPIC>
      </ITEM>
     </FOLDER>
    </FOLDER>
   </FOLDER>
  </FOLDER>
 </FOLDER>
</DOCUMENT>
```

My desired output XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DOCUMENT name="myname">
 <FOLDER key="1">
  <FOLDER key="11">
   <FOLDER key="111">
    <FOLDER key="1111">
     <FOLDER key="11111">
      <ITEM key="11111a">
       <TOPIC id="31" key="11111a1">
        <REF link="11111a1"/>
       </TOPIC>
      </ITEM>
     </FOLDER>
    </FOLDER>
    <FOLDER key="1112">
     <FOLDER key="11121">
      <ITEM key="11121a">
       <TOPIC id="31" key="11121a1">
        <REF link="11121a1"/>
       </TOPIC>
      </ITEM>
     </FOLDER>
    </FOLDER>
   </FOLDER>
  </FOLDER>
 </FOLDER>
</DOCUMENT>
```

My XSLT :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>  
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
  
    <xsl:template match="ITEM"> 
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test=" count(child::*) = 1 
                                 and  
                                 TOPIC[not(@id='31')]">     
                </xsl:when>
                
                <xsl:otherwise>                             
                    <ITEM><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></ITEM>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="TOPIC">    
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test=" not(@id='31')">    
                </xsl:when>
                
                <xsl:otherwise>                             
                    <TOPIC><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></TOPIC>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>               
    </xsl:template>             
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My produced output XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DOCUMENT name="myname">
 <FOLDER key="1">
  <FOLDER key="11">
   <FOLDER key="111">
    <FOLDER key="1111">
     <FOLDER key="11111">
      <ITEM key="11111a">
       <TOPIC id="31" key="11111a1">
        <REF link="11111a1"/>
       </TOPIC>
      </ITEM>
     </FOLDER>
     <FOLDER key="11112">
      <ITEM key="11112b"/>
     </FOLDER>
    </FOLDER>
    <FOLDER key="1112">
     <FOLDER key="11121">
      <ITEM key="11121a">
       <TOPIC id="31" key="11121a1">
        <REF link="11121a1"/>
       </TOPIC>
      </ITEM>
     </FOLDER>
     <FOLDER key="11122"/>
    </FOLDER>
   </FOLDER>
  </FOLDER>
 </FOLDER>
</DOCUMENT>
```

The following node should be removed :

```
<FOLDER key="11112">
    <ITEM key="11112a">
        <TOPIC id="46" key="11112a1">
            <REF link="11112a1"/>
        </TOPIC>
    </ITEM>
    <ITEM key="11112b">
        <TOPIC id="54" key="11112b1">
            <REF link="11112b1"/>
        </TOPIC>
        <TOPIC id="72" key="11112b2">
            <REF link="11112b2"/>
        </TOPIC>
    </ITEM>
</FOLDER>
```

But, it becomes :

```
<FOLDER key="11112">
    <ITEM key="11112b"/>
</FOLDER>
```

The followind node should be removed :

```
<FOLDER key="11122">
    <ITEM key="11122a">
        <TOPIC id="46" key="11122a1">
            <REF link="11122a1"/>
        </TOPIC>
    </ITEM>
    <ITEM key="11122b">
        <TOPIC id="46" key="11122b1">
            <REF link="11122b1"/>
        </TOPIC>
    </ITEM>
</FOLDER>
```

But it becomes :

```
<FOLDER key="11122"/>
</FOLDER>
```

Mostly, the problem lies in :

- count(child::*) = 1  because I did not manage to select and test
  all children having an Id among the Id sublist,
- at FOLDER level, be able to probe for the rules (i) and (ii).

Thank you for help.

---

**ADDED #1**

Hi Michael,

I beta tested your Xpath 2.0 solution and found out that some TOPICs with IDs to be removed are not removed. For example, if within an ITEM, you have one TOPIC to be kept and one or more TOPIC to be removed, this or those latter are not removed.

When I read your Path 2.0 solution, I don't understand why.

The modified input XML from yours :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DOCUMENT name="myname">
   <FOLDER key="1">
      <FOLDER key="11">
         <FOLDER key="111">
            <FOLDER key="1111">
               <FOLDER key="11111">
                  <ITEM key="11111a">
                     <TOPIC id="31" key="11111a1">
                        <REF link="11111a1"/>
                     </TOPIC>
                  </ITEM>
               </FOLDER>
               <FOLDER key="11112">
                  <ITEM key="11112a">
                     <TOPIC id="46" key="11112a1">
                        <REF link="11112a1"/>
                     </TOPIC>
                  </ITEM>
                  <ITEM key="11112b">
                     <TOPIC id="31" key="11112b1">
                        <REF link="11112b1"/>
                     </TOPIC>
                     <TOPIC id="46" key="11112b2">
                        <REF link="11112b2"/>
                     </TOPIC>
                  </ITEM>
               </FOLDER>
            </FOLDER>
            <FOLDER key="1112">
               <FOLDER key="11121">
                  <ITEM key="11121a">
                     <TOPIC id="31" key="11121a1">
                        <REF link="11121a1"/>
                     </TOPIC>
                     <TOPIC id="46" key="11121a2">
                        <REF link="11121a1"/>
                     </TOPIC>
                     <TOPIC id="46" key="11121a3">
                        <REF link="11121a1"/>
                     </TOPIC>
                  </ITEM>
               </FOLDER>
               <FOLDER key="11122">
                  <ITEM key="11122a">
                     <TOPIC id="46" key="11122a1">
                        <REF link="11122a1"/>
                     </TOPIC>
                  </ITEM>
                  <ITEM key="11122b">
                     <TOPIC id="46" key="11122b1">
                        <REF link="11122b1"/>
                     </TOPIC>
                  </ITEM>
               </FOLDER>
            </FOLDER>
         </FOLDER>
      </FOLDER>
   </FOLDER>
</DOCUMENT>
```

The XSLT file is yours from fiddle.

The produced output XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DOCUMENT name="myname">
   <FOLDER key="1">
      <FOLDER key="11">
         <FOLDER key="111">
            <FOLDER key="1111">
               <FOLDER key="11111">
                  <ITEM key="11111a">
                     <TOPIC id="31" key="11111a1">
                        <REF link="11111a1"/>
                     </TOPIC>
                  </ITEM>
               </FOLDER>
               <FOLDER key="11112">
                  <ITEM key="11112b">
                     <TOPIC id="31" key="11112b1">
                        <REF link="11112b1"/>
                     </TOPIC>
                     <TOPIC id="46" key="11112b2">
                        <REF link="11112b2"/>
                     </TOPIC>
                  </ITEM>
               </FOLDER>
            </FOLDER>
            <FOLDER key="1112">
               <FOLDER key="11121">
                  <ITEM key="11121a">
                     <TOPIC id="31" key="11121a1">
                        <REF link="11121a1"/>
                     </TOPIC>
                     <TOPIC id="46" key="11121a2">
                        <REF link="11121a1"/>
                     </TOPIC>
                     <TOPIC id="46" key="11121a3">
                        <REF link="11121a1"/>
                     </TOPIC>
                  </ITEM>
               </FOLDER>
            </FOLDER>
         </FOLDER>
      </FOLDER>
   </FOLDER>
</DOCUMENT>
```

We can observe that TOPICs with Id="46", that were in ITEMs with at least one TOPIC to be kept, are not removed whereas they should.

Thank you for your help.

---

**ADDED #2**

Hi Michael,

I made another beta test file #2 and suprisingly it got untouched by your Xpath 2.0 solution #2.

I created this fiddle : [beta test #2](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3MEdvhn)

I understood that that your Xpath 2.0 solution #2 weeds out the FOLDER or ITEM that does not contain any Id to keep but it does not weed out TOPICs within a kept ITEM.

It is true that my initial beta test#1 file did not provide this case that I thought was obvious.

I think that :

```
<xsl:template match="(TOPIC)[not(self::TOPIC[@id=$ids])]"/>
```

will make it.

Comment: Are you limited to XSLT 1.0?

Comment: Hi Michael, I can use 2.0 if necessary but I never looked at it yet. I will if necessary.

Comment: Re your ADDED #2: you forgot to include TOPIC in the expression: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3MEdvhn/1

Comment: Yes thank you Michael.

Comment: My big XML went through your solution Xpath 2.0 without any flaw (I checked line by line with the help of vi regex ;-) ) It is amazing to achieve such a work in an almost one-liner. Time to move to Xpath 2.0. Thank you so much for your help Michael.

Comment: *"It is amazing to achieve such a work in an almost one-liner."* Yes, that is the power of a functional language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The sublist of IDs to be kept is 31 (may be more than one but to simplify I use one)

With only one `id` to keep, the expected output can be easily produced using:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="FOLDER[not(descendant::TOPIC[@id='31'])] | ITEM[not(descendant::TOPIC[@id='31'])]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, if you have a list of more than one, or even with a list of one that needs to be populated dynamically at runtime, things get more complicated - because in XSLT 1.0 a pattern cannot reference a variable or a parameter.

---

In **XSLT 2.0** you could define a variable as a sequence of allowed `id`s, then remove the unwanted nodes using:

```
<xsl:template match="(FOLDER | ITEM)[not(descendant::TOPIC[@id=$ids])]"/>
```

**Demo**: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gVrvcxw

---

**ADDED:**

Apparently you can have sibling `TOPIC`s where some are wanted and some not. So change the above to:

```
<xsl:template match="(FOLDER | ITEM | TOPIC)[not(descendant-or-self::TOPIC[@id=$ids])]"/>
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, in the actual version of the original XML file, there is 44 different IDs. This number is subject to vary with the versions. I had to tailored the src xml file joined to make the problem easy for posting. I can try to make another one with a sublist of more than one Id. I assume that two or more would be the same.

Comment: Moreover if you say that it is not do able in 1.0, I will dig in 2.0.

Comment: Anything is doable in XSLT 1.0. Just not as simple. Can the list be hard-coded into the XSLT stylesheet? And which XSLT 1.0 processor would you be using?

Comment: Yes, in addition of the desired sublist, the list of all IDs of the document could be coded in the XSLT after extraction of the XML document by any means. I use the last Java version of Saxonica HE at this time.

Comment: The latest version of Saxon (not Saxonica) supports XSLT 3.0.

Comment: Thank you for the XSLT 2.0 solution. I will review how it works with my original file. And my bad for Saxonica instead of Saxon ;)

Comment: Thanks Michael, your added "self" seems to do the trick :)